# Python + Jira (lib) How to change "updated" fileld

Tags: python, jira

Could I change "updated" field for Jira issue without changing any others fields for the issue?

I want to update this filed let's say in the "silent mode" without changing values in the other fields.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

without having used jira-python, i guess you can't. That would break the meaning of the updated field, when setting "updated" to a new value, although there hasn't been any update. In which situation would that make sense?

Comment: My app copy and update the Jira issues into the local DB.
Yesterday, I wanted to update this field to show that this task was copied into the local DB. But in the morning with fresh head, I understand that it was my very stupid idea and I don't understand the logic of that. Anyway thank you for answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can't. Please see [this](https://community.atlassian.com/t5/JIRA-questions/How-set-quot-Created-quot-and-quot-Updated-quot-issue-date/qaq-p/205585), [this](https://jira.atlassian.com/browse/JRASERVER-38572) and [this](https://community.atlassian.com/t5/JIRA-questions/Change-the-date-and-time-of-creation-and-updated-tasks/qaq-p/368676) for more information.